# creating a find and replace application in php

Tags: php, html

i have a php code :

```
<?php
$offset=0;
if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['searchfor']) && isset($_POST['replacewith']))
{
$text=$_POST['text'];
$search=$_POST['searchfor'];
$replace=$_POST['replacewith'];
$search_length=strlen($search);
    if(!empty($text)&&!empty($search)&&!empty($replace))
    {
        while($strpos=strpos($text,$search,$offset))
        {

        $offset=$strpos + $search_length;
        $text=substr_replace($text,$replace,$strpos,$search_length);

        }
        echo $text;

    }
    else
    {
    echo 'pls fill in all fields';
    }
}

?>
<form action='string_search.php' method='POST'>
<textarea name='text' rows='6' cols='30'></textarea><br><br>
Search For:
<input type='text' name='searchfor'><br><br>
Replace with:
<input type='text' name='replacewith'><br><br>
<input type='submit' value='find and replace'>
</form>
```

When i type a string.Forexample 'i found my dog' in textarea and search for 'dog' in 'search for' then replace with 'cat' in 'replace' then submit it will out put 'i found my cat'.However it always output the original string ('i found my dog').I don't know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use:

```
while($strpos=strpos($text,$search,$offset)) {
    $offset=$strpos + $search_length;
    $text=substr_replace($text,$replace,$strpos,$search_length);
}
echo $text;
```

??

I think its the same if you just use:

```
$strpos=strpos($text,$search);
$text=substr_replace($text,$replace,$strpos,$search_length);
echo $text;
```

And probably is your while who is doing the bad work. I don't know, it's a suggestion. With this, your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$offset = 0;

if (isset($_POST['user_input_box']) && isset($_POST['search']) &&  isset($_POST['replace'])) {
    
    $user_input_box = $_POST['user_input_box'];
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $replace =$_POST['replace'];

//To check whether above code work or not

    //  echo $user_input_box = $_POST['user_input_box'];
    //  echo $search = $_POST['search'];
    //  echo $replace = $_POST['replace'];

$search_length = strlen($search);

if (!empty($_POST['user_input_box']) && !empty($_POST['search']) &&  !empty($_POST['replace'])) {
    
while ($string_position=strpos($user_input_box, $search ,$offset)) {
```

// to check while and strpos

```
        // echo $string_position."<br>";
        // echo $offset = $string_position + $search_length;
        
         $offset = $string_position + $search_length;
         $user_input_box = substr_replace($user_input_box, $replace,$string_position,$search_length );
}
echo $user_input_box;
            }

else{
    echo "Please fill the complete fields.";
}

}
 ?>

 <form method="POST" action="eleven0.php">
    
    <textarea cols="34" rows="12" name="user_input_box"></textarea>
<br><br>
    <label>Search For: </label> <br>
    <input type="text" name="search"><br><br>
    <label>Replace With: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="replace"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Find and Replace">
 </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.